# Getting Error 0x80131509 whenever I try to create a new empty project (using vs2012 as it's what my uni prefers)

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2012

[this is the error message the post is about](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uxVMO.png)
[I also got this message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7zRBg.png)

When I saw these issues, I ran a repair and after it finished came across Error 0x800b0101 talking about a license missing and my device clock needing to be fixed
Another one about an MSI package's installation failing: Error 0x80070643
I restarted vs2012 anyway, and the same errors in the screenshots persisted. It's hard to find help on vs2012 specifically, so I'm hoping for your help, thanks in advance